# Get dictionary from function in VBA

Tags: vba, dictionary

I would like to get a dictionary from a function in VBA.

I tried this:

```
Dim dic As Object
' Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dic = DicCreation()

Function DicCreation() As Variant
    ' dictionary creation
    DicCreation = dic
End Function
```

I used `Variant` because I couldn't seem to use `Scripting.Dictionary`. I deleted `Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` because I thought that the problems came from there.

At the moment, with the program above, I get `Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment` when it gets back to `Set dic = DicCreation()`.

Comment: Why don't you share an example of how you might use this? Please explain using simple words. At the moment, it looks like you want to create a function so you would be able to use `Set dic = DicCreation` instead of `Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`. Is that what you're after?

Comment: To be able to use Scripting.DIctionary you have to add a reference to The Microsoft Scripting Runtime.  In the Ide use Tools.References, scroll to find the scripting runtime then ensure that you have ticked the check box.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I wanted to get back a dictionary from ``DicCreation()``. The answer provided solved the problem. I forgot the ``Set`` keyword to return an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return a dictionary from a function you have to create the dictionary in that function. When returning it you have to use the `set` keyword.

```
Function DicCreation() As Object
    Dim dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    ' fill dictionary with data
    Set DicCreation = dict
End Function
```

Then you can use it with your posted code

```
Dim dic As Object
Set dic = DicCreation()
```